# How to wait for list of Maybe items to complete in RxJava2?

Tags: android, rx-java2

*Apologies in advance if I lack a basic understanding of how to use RxJava2, because this seems to me something that should be quite fundamental. I've wracked my brains with unsuccessful Google searches, so welcome any resource recommendations. I've opted to use a 'sanitized' representation of my workaround code for the sake of clarity.*

---

## Problem description

I have an RxJava2 function `asyncCallForList()` that returns a `Maybe<Arraylist<CustomClass>>`. Each `CustomClass` object in this list only has a few basic fields populated (e.g. the source database only contains a unique identifier and a title string for each item).

The full data required for each item is in another database location, which is retrieved using another function `asyncCallForItem(uid)`, which returns a `Maybe<CustomClass>` based on the unique identifier, where the encapsulated `CustomClass` has all the required data. This function is to be called for each item in the list returned by `asyncCallForList()`.

**The desired functionality is to update my UI once all the objects in the list have been populated.**

---

### *Workaround #1*

It is easy enough to loop through the resulting array list in the `doOnSuccess()` attached to the initial `Maybe<Arraylist<CustomClass>>`, then update my UI in the `doOnSuccess()` on the `Maybe<CustomClass>` returned by the subsequent asynchronous calls. This is not an acceptable workaround as there will be an unknown number of UI updates being made (the initial list returned could have any amount of items) and will hurt performance.

---

### *Workaround #2*

This gets the desired outcome but feels like the wrong way to go about it - I suspect there is a more elegant RxJava2 solution. Basically, I create a custom `Observable` in which loop through the items in the list and get the full data for each. However, rather than update the UI each time I populate a `CustomClass` item, I increase a counter, then check if the counter exceeds or equals the initial list size. When this condition is met I call the `onComplete()` method for the observable's emitter and update the UI there.

```
private void fetchRemoteDataAndUpdateUi() {

    //Counter reset to zero before any asynchronous calls are made.
    int count = 0;

    Maybe<ArrayList<CustomClass>> itemList = asyncCallForList();
    Consumer<ArrayList<CustomClass>> onListReturnedSuccess;

    onListReturnedSuccess = new Consumer<ArrayList<CustomClass >>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(ArrayList<CustomClass> list) throws Exception {
            //Custom observable created here, in which the resulting array list is processed.
            listObservable = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<CustomClass>() {
                @Override
                public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<CustomClass> e) throws Exception {
                    for (CustomClass customClass : list) {
                        final CustomClass thisCustomClass = customClass;
                        //Call to get full data on list item called here.
                        asyncCallForItem(customClass.getUid())
                                .doOnSuccess(new Consumer<CustomClass>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void accept(CustomClass customClass) throws Exception {
                                        thisCustomClass.update(customClass);
                                        e.onNext(thisCustomClass);
                                        count++;
                                        if (count >= list.size()) {
                                            e.onComplete();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).subscribe();
                    }
                }
            });

            listObservable
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<CustomClass>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(CustomClass customClass) {
                            //Here I add the populated CustomClass object to an ArrayList field that is utilised by the UI.
                            listForUi.add(customClass);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                            //Here the UI is finally updated once all CustomClass objects have been populated.
                            updateUi();
                        }
                    });
        }
    };


    //Kick everything off.
    itemList.doOnSuccess(onListReturnedSuccess).subscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`flatMap` it!

```java
asyncCallForList()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.flatMapSingle(list ->
    Flowable.fromIterable(list)
    .flatMapMaybe(item -> 
        asyncCallForItem(item.id)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .doOnSuccess(response -> {
            // copy state from the original item
            response.text = item.text;
        })
    , 1) // number of concurrent item calls
    .toList()
)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(successList -> { /* update UI */ }, error -> { /* report error */ });
```

Comment: Thanks, this certainly looks better than my workaround. Will try this out when I get the chance and report back. Will also read up on Flowable and Flatmap - seems to be what I'm missing in my understanding of RxJava functionality.